# VLC stream with input options

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, kodi

I'm trying to stream in CVLC for XBMC. My problem is that I can't, because I'm not just using a file stream, but rather a Decklink protocol, and I need input options. I can't find any resources on how to do that.

I tried to make VLM file:

```
new channel1 broadcast enabled
setup channel1 input decklink://{--decklink-video-connection="hdmi" --decklink-mode="Hi60" --rtsp-timeout 0}
setup channel1 output #rtp{mux=ts,dst=localhost,port=1234,sdp=sap://,name="Channel 1"}

control channel1 play
```

But that is not working even without double brackets.

Command:

```
cvlc -vvv decklink:// --decklink-video-connection="hdmi" --decklink-mode="Hi60" --rtsp-timeout 0
```

is working fine. But i can't stream it even from the CMD line:

```
cvlc -vvv decklink:// --decklink-video-connection="hdmi" --decklink-mode="Hi60" --rtsp-timeout 0 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=300,fps=25,scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=64,channels=2}:std{access=rtmp,mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=rtmp://127.0.0.0:1935}'
```

I tried many combination. The input for the stream is an ordinary HDMI input.

Any suggestions on how to stream this?